# Braintree Api Integration with cakephp 3.0

Tags: integration, cakephp-3.0, payment, braintree, gateway

I've an issue with braintree api integration and having an issue with generating the token from api, but it's showing an error-
"Class 'App\Controller\Braintree\ClientToken' not found".

I've adding the Braintree library in webroot directory and include by-
require_once('braincard\includes\braintree_init.php');

I'm generating the braintree token with following function.
Braintree\ClientToken::generate();

Regards

Comment: which plugin you have used of braintree with cake php 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply using `Braintree\ClientToken::generate();`, you are indicating that it is relative to the current namespace, which is \App\Controller. Try `\Braintree\ClientToken::generate();` instead, this should work.

You might also investigate how you can use Composer to move the library to a move "Cake-ish" folder (having it in the `webroot` sounds like a potential security hole), and autoload the class without needing to resort to `require_once` or the like.